# Disable TeamViewer from "stealing" Port 80?

Tags: remote-desktop, port, teamviewer

How can you disable TeamViewer from using/reserving port 80? I am certain in the previous version <v4.1.6 there used to be a radio button option in "options" which disabled it from needing it, but now I cannot find it.

Is port 80 serisouly required by this remote desktop app? It is conflicting with IIS on our development server and becoming a real pain.

Thanks all.

Comment: This question came up when I found an HTTP server on my network, serving the page: "This site is running TeamViewer.
Free Port 80 for other applications in advanced settings."
Based on Deanna's answer below, it is presumably running TeamViewer <9.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you enable the Direct-In Modus? You can disable it in

```
   Options > Advanced > Network > TeamViewer DirectIn check
```

From the manual, page 59 ([PDF](http://www.teamviewer.com/help/teamviewer_manual.pdf)):

> Check Opens a
>   dialog where the availability of
>   TeamViewer is checked. The DirectIn
>   Ports 80 and 5938 do not have to be
>   opened , however, TeamViewer can use
>   these ports - if available - for
>   establishing faster connections.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at that checkbox, paused on it, then moved on.  If only I clicked on options for it I would have noticed it wanted to use port 80! :) Thanks.

Comment: Page 59 of the PDF seems incorrect; I found the info about DirectIn options on page 78 of 81 (the PDF itself regards it as page 82).

Answer (score 6):

```
Options > Advanced > Show Advanced Options > Don't use incoming ports 80 and 443
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Open port 5938 (TCP) on your firewall.
2. Change the following registry keys.

   - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
     TeamViewer\Version4]  Key  ’GatewayAllowed’ set to 0
     *
     [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version4]  Key  ’ListenHttp’ set to 0

Answer (score 3):

On the new teamviewer you go to advanced settings and then **Don't use port 80**

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows 7 x64, you will find that the registry keys are in a different location. I have searched the registry and cannot find anything along the lines of 'GatewayAllowed'. The other key is as follows:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version6\ListenHttp

Answer (score 2):

A fresh install of TeamViewer 9 no longer hijacks port 80 by default.
For prior versions, the other fixes normally work.

Answer (score 1):

The DirectIn check merely checks whether port 80 is forwarded through your router, it does not stop hijacking port 80.  There is a registry change that you can make (two values need to be changes, one obvious, one non).  I don't have the details with me, but if you *telephone* TV tech support, ignore their "this is just how it works" and insist on talking to a tech, you may be able to get it.  I'll post the changes as soon as I get to my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the Apache server before teamviewer seems to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behavior in TeamViewer version 5.1 or newer.

Open TeamViewer options under Extras > Options > Advanced. Enable the option "Don't use incoming port 80 (recommended for web servers only)" so that TeamViewer won’t try to take the Port again.