# Port 80 is being used by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, port-80

After installing WAMP server 2.5 on Server 2012 R2 I tried to run it but it just said this

```
Your port 80 is actually used by : 
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

I've look at every post I can find about this, there's no Web Deployment service running, IIS isn't even installed.

This is what I got from `netsh http show urlacl`

```
URL Reservations:
-----------------

Reserved URL            : http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

Reserved URL            : https://+:5986/wsman/
    User: NT SERVICE\WinRM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT SERVICE\Wecsvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517)

Reserved URL            : http://+:47001/wsman/
    User: NT SERVICE\WinRM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT SERVICE\Wecsvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517)

Reserved URL            : http://*:2869/
    User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;LS)

Reserved URL            : http://*:5357/
    User: BUILTIN\Users
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;BU)(A;;GX;;;LS)

Reserved URL            : https://*:5358/
    User: BUILTIN\Users
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;BU)(A;;GX;;;LS)

Reserved URL            : https://+:443/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/
    User: NT SERVICE\SstpSvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: Yes
    User: BUILTIN\Administrators
        Listen: No
        Delegate: No
    User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: Yes
        SDDL: D:(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-80-3435701886-799518250-3791383489-3228296122-2938884314)(A;;GR;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;SY)

Reserved URL            : http://+:80/0131501b-d67f-491b-9a40-c4bf27bcb4d4/
    User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS)

Reserved URL            : https://+:443/C574AC30-5794-4AEE-B1BB-6651C5315029/
    User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS)

Reserved URL            : http://+:80/116B50EB-ECE2-41ac-8429-9F9E963361B7/
    User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS)

Reserved URL            : http://*:8989/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

Reserved URL            : http://+:5985/wsman/
    User: NT SERVICE\WinRM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT SERVICE\Wecsvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517)
```

Any ideas anyone?

Edit: I've also just just noticed that when I go to localhost in my browser it shows a 404, which would surely mean that there's something there? As when I navigate to localhost on a different computer, with nothing running on port 80, it says it can't connect. Not sure how useful this is as it may already be obvious but I thought it was worth adding anyway.

Comment: Try `netstat -aon | find /i "80"` in cmd prompt. Then open task manager and add the PID column to the process tab. You should then be able to match the process in the cmd to the one in task manager

Comment: It came out with PID 4, which is System.

Comment: I've also just just noticed that when I go to localhost in my browser it shows a 404, which would surely mean that there's something there? As when I navigate to localhost on a different computer, with nothing running on port 80, it says it can't connect.

Comment: What other applications have you got installed on the server? SQL for example?

Comment: BubbleUPnP Server, CouchPotato, Chrome, Defraggler, EaseUS Backup Advanced Server, Java 8, Mezzmo, MySQL server, Node.js, Virtualbox, Peerblock, Pulseway, Pusbullet, Python, Sonnar, Subsonic, Teamviewer, Unified Remote, WinDirStat and WinRAR.

Comment: @Raf my money is on Teamviewer: http://serverfault.com/questions/11202/disable-teamviewer-from-stealing-port-80

Comment: @MarkHenderson after poking around Teamviewer settings and researching this, it appears that the issue was fixed in v9. I uninstalled Teamviewer and rebooted but the port 80 issue was still apparent, so I don't think Teamviewer is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

WAMP on Server 2012 - port 80 is used by Server : Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0 [Solved]
03-20-2015, 03:45 AM
I didn't see this documented anywhere else so I thought I would document it here.

We wanted to run the Apache web server on a new Windows Server 2012 R2 install.

The Apache service wouldn't start because TCP/IP port 80 was in use.

The error was,
Port 80 is used by "Server : Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0".

The obvious thing was to disable the IIS web server, which can also use port 80. But this didn't solve the problem.

It turns out there are a long list of other services that can also use Port 80: 
These include the following services:

- SQL Server Reporting Services
- World Wide Web Publishing Service
- Web Deployment Agent Service
- Branch Cache Service (<== This was the important one for us, and also the one that is least documented)

https://www.passmark.com/forum/general/5273-wamp-on-server-2012-port-80-is-used-by-server-microsoft-httpapi-2-0-solved

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was running without virtual hosts and didn't want them

So I disabled & changed the httpd-vhosts.conf to Require all granted

VirtualHost configuration:

```
Default server: localhost
```

*** WARNING: No VirtualHost defined

================== COMPLETE RESULT ==================
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   localhost (C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:5)

commented line 180

## LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

comment line 512

## Virtual hosts

## Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

#

## Virtual Hosts

#

ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local

#

## Virtual Hosts

#

ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

Now this worked for me - but I just want to ask if this is going to cause a security issue I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is identifying which process is listening on a specific port, for example with the port 80, below command can be used to find the related process ID:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :80
```

A response might look like below:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8017           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       740
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8018           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3100
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4368
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4368
```

The process ID can be found in the most right column.

In my case, the process with ID 4 was listening on port 80, and process ID 4 belongs to SYSTEM.

I eventually found out that Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) was the culprit and as I no longer needed the role, I removed it from the Roles and Features wizard and the problem was solved :)